# Save As PDF VBA Function issue

Tags: vba, excel

I made a simple function to save all my tabs into a destination folder. However, after implementing the total process I realized this won't work week to week.

To solve the issue I'm having from one week to another, I need the files to be pdfs instead of .xlsx. I attempted to fix this myself by modifying the already existing function, however, when I open the pdfs it generates, they are "corrupted" or so says Adobe.

Please see below:

```
Sub SaveFilesInFolder()
'
'This is a function for saving each worksheet as a workbook in a destination folder
'

'
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook

    For Each sh In Worksheets
        SheetName = sh.Name
        sh.Copy

        With ActiveWorkbook
            .SaveAs FileName:="C:\Example\" & SheetName & ".pdf"
            .Close SaveChanges:=True
        End With

    Next sh

End Sub
```

I am aware of ExportAsFileFormat but I am having trouble getting that to work with the entire workbook that has 100+ tabs.

Any recommendations are appreciated.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub Test()
For Each sht In Sheets
  sht.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="C:\" & sht.Name & ".pdf"
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This works but I need each tab to be a separate PDF file. Thank you for your input.

Comment: Abe, it is prompting an error that says, "We could not find anything to print".

I copied and pasted your code and just changed the destination folder.

Comment: If any of the tabs are totally blank, you'll get that error. You can use on error resume next to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the [ExportAsFixedFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-exportasfixedformat-method-excel) method.

```
.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="C:\Example\" & SheetName & ".pdf"
```

Comment: I attempted this but an issue caused me to shy away from it. It was prompting me to save an excel file for every worksheet.